# Apache flooded with Error Logs

Tags: apache-2.2, security

The filesystem on my system is becoming too high in a relatively short period of time.

OS : Oracle Linux 2.6.18-274.0.0.0.1.el5

WebServer : Apache 2.2.23

The Error logs are filled like this :
[Mon Apr 15 06:45:50 2013] [error] Error receiving content (expected 4000 bytes, got 0)

These logs are increasing at much higher speed and I am clueless as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I were yopu I'd be more worried about the fact that my webserver is not working or getting hammered by an attack rather than the filesystem filling up.

Assuming the error log is the cause...then what are these requests for? Where do they originate from? Is it a DOS attack? Is it a problem with the webserver connecting to a back end process? Have you eliminated the [known causes](https://github.com/projectwonder/wonder/issues/26) for this error?

Comment: The web server is working. I am able to see access logs. The problem is i am not sure if its DoS attack as this issue is happening only on couple of servers, not all. We do use mod_webobjects but our CPU is fine.

Comment: File system is getting to 100%, then again the error file is getting recreated ..then again 100% .cycle is getting repeated.

Comment: `We do use mod_webobjects` - that's a remarkable coincidence.

Comment: indeed .. but we have been using it for years but we are seeing issue today only, and strangely only on a couple of servers.